# ListView highlight unselected rows

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Scenario.
Say list view has 5 items. When I click on a particular item, that particular item gets highlighted. When i click on another item, the previous item is unselected and the new item is highlighted. 
 I am able to do so by holding 2 views. CurrentSelectedItemView and PreviousSelectedItemView. Using these two views I am changing the text color and backgrounds of these two rows. But how do i change the color and background of other rows. I do not want to reset the adapter every time a row is selected.

Say text color is black and background is white. When a row is selected,the colors reverse. For other rows,I need to change the text color to grey. I able to do fr 2 rows only... current and previous.

Is there any simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You should keep track of last selected index to change the background of previous selected item.

Comment: That I have done.  CurrentSelectedItemView and PreviousSelectedItemView. What about the other rows. Is there no way other than refreshing the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

To make changes in listview you need to alteast called adapter.notifydatachanged()